# data replication in opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight

Our application periodically does topology discovery and merges it in MD-SAL with the previously discovered data using MERGE operation. Usually the changes are very small if any. We work in the cluster environment. 
Does Opendaylight replicate only the changes to other members or the full data tree? If the latter is correct, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each transaction, it replicates only the change operations issued in the transaction.

Comment: Great! I have one more question about MERGE operation. As I understand, to do MERGE md-sal has to read a tree into memory. Can this read data be used for another MERGE within the same transaction or within the same transaction chain? If I need to do lots of merges of subtrees, will it improve performance if within the same transaction chain I preliminary read the entire tree that includes all these subtrees?

Comment: If this answer was adequate, please mask as answered then I'll address your next question :)